# Показать Splash screen до загрузки WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

У меня есть простое приложение, которое загружает сайт:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://taxxx.ru/nc/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Я хочу показать пользователю LaunchScreen до того, как сайт не загрузится. Но не могу найти как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно над вашим вью контроллером (где идет загрузка) сделать еще вью, содержащую картинку как на экране ланч скрина, чтобы было незаметно, когда ланч скрин убирается. А уже эту вью с картинкой убирать (резко или плавно, как хотите) по событию окончания загрузки, который можно перехватить, если мне не изменяет память, вот этим методом https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview. Только для этой функции, не забудьте подписать ваш вью контроллер под WKNavigationDelegate и сделать делегатом.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen не предназначен для подобного. Да и не есть хорошо так делать. Что если сайт не загрузится?

Но если так хочется - делаете дубликат вьюшки с LaunchScreen и накладываете его на своем контроллере. После окончания загрузки в методе делегата

```
webView(_:didFinish:)
```

Скрываете / убираете эту вьюшку.